# How to calculate an irregular polygons angle?

Tags: c++

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H23ZJ.png)

I can calculate the angles which is lower than 180 degree but if it is bigger than 180 degree I only get the value of the exterior angle (the smaller one). 
As you can see in the picture if I calculate the red angle I get the value of the green one.

```
    float angle1 = atan2(points[i-1].y - points[i].y, points[i-1].x - points[i].x);
    float angle2 = atan2(points[i+1].y - points[i].y, points[i+1].x - points[i].x);
    float validAngle = fabs(angle1 - angle2);

    printf("angle: %f\n", validAngle / M_PI * 180);
```

[image]

Comment: `angle = min(angle, 360-angle)` That said, this is a perfect application for the inner product (aka, cross product).

Comment: @3Dave: inner product is the dot product.

Comment: @geza Correct. Pretend I said "vector product." :) Even though it's a scalar in 2D.

Comment: You can calculate angle by: atan2(cross(a, b), dot(a, b))